# Convert a list of dataframes to a list of dictionaries with custom keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Input**

> A list of dataframes. Each dataframe can have different length and the total number of columns can also differ. Each dataframe will have a column named "special". Except for this special column the other column names will be unique across this list.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"column1":["1","2","3"], "column2":["4","5","6"], "special":["1000","2000","3000"]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"column3": ["1","2","3","4"], "column4": ["8","9","10","11"], "column5":["12","13","14","15"],"special":["1000","2000","3000","4000"]})

df_list = [df_1,df_2]
```

**Output**

> A list of dictionaries with where each dictionary has 3 fixed keys: *name*, *value* and *special*. 
>   Here is the expected output if df_list contained only df_1. Mentioning this for simplication:

```
[{'name': 'column1', 'value': '1', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column1', 'value': '2', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column1', 'value': '3', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '4', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '5', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '6', 'special': '3000'}]
```

> Here is the expected output if df_list contains both df_1 and df_2:

```
[{'name': 'column1', 'value': '1', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column1', 'value': '2', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column1', 'value': '3', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '4', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '5', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '6', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '1', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '2', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '3', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '4', 'special': '4000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '8', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '9', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '10', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '11', 'special': '4000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '12', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '13', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '14', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '15', 'special': '4000'}]
```

**Current Code**

> I have been able to do this using the apply() method on the dataframe but I suspect that there might be an even better to do it. Here is how I am doing it right now:

```
for data_frame in df_list:
    for column in data_frame:
        if column != "special":
            result.extend(data_frame.apply(lambda x:{"name":column,"value":x[column],"special":x["special"]},axis=1).to_list())
```

> Can you suggest any optimizations or a different way of doing this? I also thought of concatenating all the data frames and running only the inner loop but since they are not all of equal length, there will be a lot of NaN values. Would that be a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUc, you can try `concat` + `melt`:

```
print(pd.concat(df_list,sort=False).melt('special',var_name='name')
     .dropna(subset=['value'])[['name','value','special']].to_dict('records'))
```

---

```
[{'name': 'column1', 'value': '1', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column1', 'value': '2', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column1', 'value': '3', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '4', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '5', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column2', 'value': '6', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '1', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '2', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '3', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column3', 'value': '4', 'special': '4000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '8', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '9', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '10', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column4', 'value': '11', 'special': '4000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '12', 'special': '1000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '13', 'special': '2000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '14', 'special': '3000'}, {'name': 'column5', 'value': '15', 'special': '4000'}]
```

Comment: Nice one @anky.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it gives the required solution. Although, I missed one additional constraint in the question :)  but this has given me the correct direction. Thanks @anky !

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create an empty list
melted_df = []

# Melt all the dfs in your list into a dataframe
for dataframe in df_list:
    temp = dataframe.melt(var_name="name", 
        id_vars=["special"], 
        value_name="value")

# Append the melted dfs into your list
melted_df.append(temp)

# Concatenate the dfs in the list
result = pd.concat(melted_df)

# Convert the df into dictionary
result.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{'special': '1000', 'name': 'column1', 'value': '1'},
 {'special': '2000', 'name': 'column1', 'value': '2'},
 {'special': '3000', 'name': 'column1', 'value': '3'},
 {'special': '1000', 'name': 'column2', 'value': '4'},
 {'special': '2000', 'name': 'column2', 'value': '5'},
 {'special': '3000', 'name': 'column2', 'value': '6'},
 {'special': '1000', 'name': 'column3', 'value': '1'},
 {'special': '2000', 'name': 'column3', 'value': '2'},
 {'special': '3000', 'name': 'column3', 'value': '3'},
 {'special': '4000', 'name': 'column3', 'value': '4'},
 {'special': '1000', 'name': 'column4', 'value': '8'},
 {'special': '2000', 'name': 'column4', 'value': '9'},
 {'special': '3000', 'name': 'column4', 'value': '10'},
 {'special': '4000', 'name': 'column4', 'value': '11'},
 {'special': '1000', 'name': 'column5', 'value': '12'},
 {'special': '2000', 'name': 'column5', 'value': '13'},
 {'special': '3000', 'name': 'column5', 'value': '14'},
 {'special': '4000', 'name': 'column5', 'value': '15'}]
```